# SQLite: How do I find the daily/weekly/monthly/yearly average of a row count

Tags: sqlite, csv

I've just started learning SQLite, and had a question.

Here is an example of what I mean.

This is my CSV:

```
date
2010-10-24
2010-10-31
2010-11-01
2011-02-14
2011-02-15
2011-02-16
2011-10-01
2012-01-15
2012-05-12
2012-05-14
2012-08-12
2012-08-26
```

My code:

```
SELECT STRFTIME('%Y-%m', date) AS 'month', COUNT() AS 'month_count'
    FROM tableName 
    GROUP BY STRFTIME('%Y-%m', date);
```

The result (in comma-delimited form):

```
month, month_count
2010-10, 2
2010-11, 1
2011-02, 3
2011-10, 1
2012-01, 1
2012-05, 2
2012-08, 2
```

What I'm looking for now, is a way to get the average number of 'month_count' per month, which is of course different from just the average of 'month_count'. That is, the former equals 0.55, while the latter equals 1.71, and I'm trying ti calculate the former.

I tried using AVG(COUNT()), though that obviously made no logical sense.

I'm guessing I'd have to store the code-generated table as a temporary file, then get the average from it, though I'm not sure how to properly write it.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Can you explain how you are getting .54?

Comment: Whoops, looks like I'm off by 1/100th, dcp. I meant to say '0.55.'. The number of months from 2010-10 to 2012-08 is 22. The total for 'month_count' is  12. 12/22 = 0.55. That's 0.55 per month.

Comment: Username- See my latest revised answer, hope the idea works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
create table test(date date);
insert into test values ('2010-10-24');
insert into test values ('2010-10-31');
insert into test values ('2010-11-01');
insert into test values ('2011-02-14');
insert into test values ('2011-02-15');
insert into test values ('2011-02-16');
insert into test values ('2011-10-01');
insert into test values ('2012-01-15');
insert into test values ('2012-05-12');
insert into test values ('2012-05-14');
insert into test values ('2012-08-12');
insert into test values ('2012-08-26');

SELECT a.tot_months 
     , b.month_diff
     , cast(a.tot_months as float) / b.month_diff avg_count
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) tot_months FROM test) a
     , (SELECT cast((strftime('%m',max(date))+12*strftime('%Y',max(date))) as int) -
               cast((strftime('%m',min(date))+12*strftime('%Y',min(date))) as int) as 'month_diff'
          FROM test) b
;
```

Output:

```
C:\scripts>sqlite3 < foo.sql
12|22|0.545454545454545
```

Comment: Hm, from that code I'm getting the same as my code, but with another column called 'avg_count' which is filled with zeroes. I'd like to learn what the syntax of your code means, so I'll check out the SQLite syntax documentation in the mean time. Thanks for responding.

Comment: @Username - ok, I downloaded SQLite and the above code is tested, so give it a shot now.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks, dcp. Now I just need to learn how the syntax works. I'm sure you're busy, though, so I don't want to take up too much of your time. So, I'll just ask: What do you think is the best way to learn the syntax? Thanks, again.

Comment: @Username - SQL syntax is best learned by example. Reading is good, but the best way is just like you just did, find problems to solve and then solve them. When you get stuck, ask here. Then learn the lessons, so next time you have a similar problem to solve, you can apply these lessons. Here, I used a concept known as inline views. Read more about them here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_inline_views.htm. If there's something specific you don't understand regarding the syntax I used, feel free to ask. Thanks.

Comment: Alright, dcp. In that case, I'd like to make educated guesses at what your code means...It looks like 'a.tot_months' and 'b.months_diff' made two different columns. 'CAST' made it so that 'tot_months' will be read as a float number -- though I'm not sure what the value of that number is. That number is divided by 'b.month_diff avg_count', but I'm not sure what that means. Since I don't understand that, I don't think I can make any good guesses as to what the rest of the code means...Thanks for responding.

Comment: @Username - "though I'm not sure what the value of that number is" The value comes from the inline view, called a. We are getting a total count of months. The a and b letters beside of those queries in the "from" clause give names to the inline views. You can think of an inline view as a computed table. Please refer to the link I gave above. In the division, we just end up dividing 12 by 22, and that's how we get the .545454. The cast to float is needed because without it, we will do integer division, and we won't get a floating point result.